# error displaying posted html

Tags: php, html, parsing, post

Im storing the contents of a div in a textaera then posting the contents to another page.

The second page should simply print out the html as if it were writen directly in that page.

The content displays except everywhere there is a " in the html, it gets printed as \"  (on the image sources and ids for example)

Why does this happen and what can I do to avoid it?

**The html:**

```
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="34"><table><tr>
      <td style="color: #333333;table-layout:fixed;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;" id="imgCell3"><img src="https://www.pnrbuilder.com/_images/itinerary/airlines_AC.gif"><br>
        AC # 7469</td>
      <td class="itinCell">06:30 AM on Tue, October 22, 2013<br>
        Newark/Elizabeth, NJ (EWR): Newark Liberty Intl. Airport</td>
      <td class="itinCell">8:03 AM on Tue, October 22, 2013 <br>
        Mississauga,&nbsp;Ontario,&nbsp;Canada (YYZ): Toronto Pearson Intl. Airport</td>
      <br>
    </tr>
  </table></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="POST"/>
```

**The php:**

```
echo '<strong>This is the email content as it was posted to the page:</strong><br>'.$_POST['message'].'<br><br><br>';
```

**The resulting source code echo'd by the php:**

```
<strong>This is the email content as it was posted to the page:</strong><br><table><tr>
      <td style=\"color: #333333;table-layout:fixed;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;\" id=\"imgCell3\"><img src=\"https://www.pnrbuilder.com/_images/itinerary/airlines_AC.gif\"><br>
        AC # 7469</td>
      <td class=\"itinCell\">06:30 AM on Tue, October 22, 2013<br>
        Newark/Elizabeth, NJ (EWR): Newark Liberty Intl. Airport</td>
      <td class=\"itinCell\">8:03 AM on Tue, October 22, 2013 <br>
        Mississauga, Ontario, Canada (YYZ): Toronto Pearson Intl. Airport</td>
      <br>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try stripslashes() in php to unescape the quotes. Refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: Lifesaver, ive been searching google for hours but didnt really know what I was looking for!